# Trainline: How to import a pdf eticket into the Trainline App?

Tags: trainline

My wife bought an eticket for me with her Trainline app for UK railways. The [Trainline Help Page](https://www.thetrainline.com/information/digital-tickets) says

```
eticket

Open the email we send you with the PDF(s) attached – this is separate to your booking confirmation email
If you like, you can add the eticket(s) to our app or Apple Wallet
```

And elsewhere it says that the advantage of an eticket that comes by mail is that you can forward it to someone else. My wife has forwarded the mail to me and I can see the pdf eticket in my mail, but I'd like to have it in my Trainline App on my phone, logged into my Trainline account. The trainline help pages are maddeningly uninformative. Is there a way to do this, please?

Answer (score 1):

From [their help](https://www.thetrainline.com/information/digital-tickets):

[image]

> **How do I use digital tickets?**
>
> We’ll show you whichever option is available for your route, just
> search your journey as normal.
>
> **Trainline etickets**
>
> **eticket**
>
> ```
> Open the email we send you with the PDF(s) attached – this is separate to your booking confirmation email
> If you like, you can add the eticket(s) to our app or Apple Wallet
> Scan the QR code from your phone at the ticket gate at the station, or show to staff
> ```
>
> **Mobile Ticket - you’ll need our app**
>
> ```
> Open our app and go to My Tickets
> Tap your Mobile Ticket to activate it just before you travel – once activated, you can’t request a refund
> Scan the QR code from your phone at the ticket gate at the station, or show to staff
> ```